Dirac operator on a manifold with boundary
I have been trying to understand construction of Dirac operator on a manifold with boundary. I came across the following paper:
Hijazi, O., Montiel, S. & Roldán, A. Eigenvalue Boundary Problems for the Dirac Operator. Commun. Math. Phys. 231, 375–390 (2002), MR1946443, Zbl 1018.58020. DOI:10.1007/s00220-002-0725-0 or this link without paywall.

I don't understand equation 7 here. The $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ has $n-1$-dimensional boundary $\partial M$. $N$ is the normal to the boundary. And $\Gamma(\mathbb{S}M)$ denotes the section of spinor bundle of the manifold $M$. Mentioned after eq. 4 in the paper, they write $D = \gamma^{i} \nabla_{i}$ ($D$ on the RHS of eq. 7) with $i = 1,\ldots, n$. From eq. 7, it looks like we are acting with Levi-Civita connection ($\nabla_{N}$) in the $N$th direction twice. I don't understand why do we do that.
As a 2nd question I wish to consider the simplest example with $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ where, the mean curvature is trivially $0$. If $(w,x,y,z)$ with $w \geq 0$ are coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, then say the boundary is at $w=0$. Naively doing this gives some strange operator.
Any help will be appreciated.

Are you sure you linked to the right paper? I do not see cropped text and equations in the paper's PDF file.

@IgorKhavkine My bad, I corrected the link. However it is behind paywall now. I cant find the arxiv link of it.

@IgorKhavkine okay found the paper on Academia.edu if you scroll down the paper is available online, to download one has to login.

https://www.academia.edu/107620777/Eigenvalue_Boundary_Problems_for_the_Dirac_Operator?uc-sb-sw=35549254 here is the paper, scroll down to see it.

Looking at the paper, the last $-$ sign in (7) is either a typo or somehow their convention has $\gamma(N)^2 = -|N|^2 = -1$. Without going through the references that establish their notation it's not clear to me.

You can take a look at the formula (11) in the paper
Bär, Christian, Paul Gauduchon, und Andrei Moroianu. „Generalized cylinders in semi-Riemannian and spin geometry“. Mathematische Zeitschrift 249, Nr. 3 (2005): 545–80.
